# Parsing snake-case returning null

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have this class below:

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class AggregationModel {
   @JsonProperty(value = "doc_count_error_upper_bound")
   private Integer docCountErrorUpperBound;

   @JsonProperty(value = "sum_other_doc_count")
   private Integer sumOtherDocCount;

   @JsonProperty(value = "buckets")
   private List<Bucket> buckets;

   public Integer getDocCountErrorUpperBound() {
       return docCountErrorUpperBound;
   }

   public void setDocCountErrorUpperBound(Integer docCountErrorUpperBound) {
      this.docCountErrorUpperBound = docCountErrorUpperBound;
   }

   public Integer getSumOtherDocCount() {
      return sumOtherDocCount;
   }

   public void setSumOtherDocCount(Integer sumOtherDocCount) {
       this.sumOtherDocCount = sumOtherDocCount;
   }

   public List<Bucket> getBuckets() {
       return buckets;
   }

   public void setBuckets(List<Bucket> buckets) {
      this.buckets = buckets;
   }
}
```

Here's the json:

```
{
  "took": 15,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
     "total": 5,
     "successful": 5,
     "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
     "total": 10,
     "max_score": 0,
     "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
     "group_by": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
           {
              "key": 439,
              "doc_count": 7,
              "average": {
                 "value": 5
              }
           }
       ]
     }
  }
}
```

Please consider the "aggregations" part only.

Only bucket is being returned fine, while the other two are returned as null. I am not sure why is that the case. I am using fasterxml.jackson.* (version 2.8.4).

Please help. 
TIA.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Post a json as well. In such form this question is not answerable.

Comment: Please review the question again.

Comment: Your class name suggests that it maps the `aggregations` subtree but i don't see `group_by` in it wich contains the elements you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test case that I wrote used Gson in the background to parse JSON, once I converted it to Jackson, it started working.

Thanks a lot.